# What is efficient way of storing IPV6 subnet Address in mongo database to check subnet validation and overlap?

Tags: java, mongodb

Storing IPV6 address as string in database and doing conversion each and every time for subnet range validation and to check overlap with existing subnets will not be efficient. Mongo DB does not support big integer datatype to store ipv6 address in integer format. So wanted to know what will be the right mongo data type to store IPV6 address for efficient processing ?

Comment: How are you processing the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this really feels like premature optimization.  Are you I/O bound or CPU bound?  If you're I/O bound then the simplest format would be to just shove it in a binary field, 16 bytes for the address and one byte for the subnet.

If you're CPU bound then it may be faster to store a larger document that has some of the parsing already done for you.  You'd have to experiment with different formats to see.

Either way, if this is truly your bottleneck, you'll probably save more time in the long run clustering your storage and compute and scaling horizontally first.